# Makefiles: Change working directory for make check

Tags: c++, makefile, cppunit

I have a C++ project that employs unit testing via CppUnit and has the following directory structure:

```
.
|-- bin
|   `-- tests
|-- src
|   `-- include
`-- test
    `-- include
```

In the top-level directory resides my Makefile.am file. I would like to use a non-recursive Makefile. I have been able to build the executable of my project in the *bin* folder and the tests for *make check* in the *bin/tests* folder.

The problem is the following:
When *make check* runs the tests, the current working directory is still the top-level directory (i.e., the directory from which I ran *make check*). Is it possible to change the working directory specifically for the test suites?

The relevant piece in my Makefile.am file is the following:

```
$(TESTDIR)=./bin/tests
check_PROGRAMS = $(TESTS)
TESTS = $(TESTDIR)clocktest

__TESTDIR_clocktest_SOURCES = test/clocktest.cpp test/unittest.cpp src/clock.cpp
__TESTDIR_clocktest_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPUNIT_CFLAGS) $(TESTCPPFLAGS)
__TESTDIR_clocktest_LDADD = $(CPPUNIT_LIBS)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `make --help`:

```
-C DIRECTORY, --directory=DIRECTORY
                            Change to DIRECTORY before doing anything.
```

I think that should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that is not what I'm looking for. Like I mentioned in my question: I use a non-recursive make and there is no Makefile residing in ./bin/tests so this is of no help to me.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. :-) I have the feeling that I am overlooking something very basic here...I have added a piece of my code. Could you provide a suggestion how I should alter this piece of code to incorporate a cd in the make rule?

Comment: I'm thinking whatever rule runs the unittest, have it run something like `cd $(TESTDIR) && ./clocktest`.

Comment: Indeed. I solved it by adding the following to the makefile: `check : $(noinst_PROGRAMS)
 (cd $(TESTDIR); ./run_tests.sh)`